# ImageMagick: Invalid ICC profile after conversion

Tags: imagemagick, rgb, photoshop, color-profile, color-management

I wrote an application which trims and resizes a bunch of images via ImageMagick. The images are also converted to grayscale. But when I try to open a converted image in Photoshop CC, the following warning appears:

> The embedded ICC profile cannot be used because the ICC profile is
>   invalid, ignoring the profile.

Plus, the image profile is in grayscale, but I want it to be in RGB. How can I achieve this with ImageMagick? I played around with the different parameters, but none worked for me.

This command is currently in use:

```
convert ${src} -type grayscale -set colorspace RGB -background white -gravity center -extent ${longest}x${longest} ${dest}
```

Also, this one didn't work either:

```
convert.exe ${src} -set colorspace RGB -set profile RGB.icc ${dest}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing any existing profile (with `-strip` or `+profile`) before adding new ones?

Comment: Thank you, `-strip` worked just fine for removing the invalid profile.

Comment: @MarkSetchell who'd guess that, these days, _removing_ a profile would do wonders, compared to merely _changing_ it (which fails more often than not)... Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to force the output PNG to be RGB is to replace $(dest) in your command with PNG24:$(dest), or use PNG32:$(dest) if your image has transparency).  If you do this, then your existing RGB color profile will be OK.

You can also try PNG8:$(dest) which will be OK if you have fewer than 256 gray levels, and will result in a smaller file size.

Comment: Both your's and Mark's answer worked for me. Seems like there was an invalid ICC profile which had to be removed, also I will use your method to write the result as a PNG24 file in order to get RGB. Thank you both!